# Students and multiple scores on many dates - Java

Tags: java, arrays, database, one-to-many, derby

I'm creating a program that is a quiz for my A-level coursework and I'm currently on the design section.

It is a class quiz and at the end of the quiz the teacher is able to store the scores for each student. The quiz will have 3 sub-quizzes so one student can have 3 different scores, but an average will be found (automatically). The quiz will be taken on multiple days, so one student will have many scores over many days. This is because the average score will be plotted against time (dates) and a graph is generated where each student is a different colour.

HERE'S MY PROBLEM:

I need the user to enter in the student names which are saved 
then they can go back every day, select a student from the drop down box and enter in their scores for the day - these scores are saved under that date
then the next day they do the same

so how do this?

- create two tables one for student details and one for scores and link them together by student ID so one-many relationship? will that be stored in a 2 dimensional array?
- Or are tables and arrays completely different methods of storing data?
  so in an array it would look like this?

  ```
  student ID1, firstname, lastname
  student ID2, firstname, lastname
  student ID3, firstname, lastname
  ```

and then scores is

```
studentID1, score1, score2, score3, average, date
studentID1, score1, score2, score3, average, date
studentID1, score1, score2, score3, average, date
```

but I want the user to find the scores through the NAME and not the ID... is that possible when using this method? Like the user will have to be able to search for a student and view all their scores for all the dates (either in tabular or graphical form) - will this work?

Also when I create these tables in `derby` database - how do i link the two together?

Comment: Please read [How Do I Ask a Good Question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

A SQL database table and an array are two different things, even though a table can be thought of like a two-dimensional array with rows and columns.

You could simply have the name as the primary key (even if it is broken into separate firstname and lastname columns), but you will run into trouble if there are ever two John Smiths in the class. If there is a unique student ID assigned to students, you would do well to use that; if not, an auto-incrementing sequence in the database is commonly used to assign an ID. (In database terms, the name would be called a natural key, the arbitrarily-assigned ID would be called a surrogate key; in my experience surrogate keys are nearly ubiquitous and work just fine.)

I wouldn't break the name up into a firstname and lastname column. What do you do with names like "Madonna", "Li Bing", and "David Lloyd George"? I would just have a name column.

When a teacher goes to select a student from the drop down box, you would populate it by doing a SELECT on the table with the student ID and the names. You don't mention if this is a web app or a Swing app or an Android app or what, but you just need to relate the item selected back to the student ID, and then you can use that to select or update the row in the second table with the test scores.

Comment: thank you :) ! it is Swing sorry , making it on the Netbeans IDE. Yes I was going to use the name as a primary key but there could be more than one person with the same name AND, I need to store multiple records for the same name which wouldn't be possible if it's unique right? Alright I'll just use an autoincrementing ID because I don't want the user to have to assign it. I was told to split the name up but it does make more sense to keep it together and oh right okay thank you SO MUCH :D